# Google Analytics Super Proxy Not Displaying Japanese Character Data

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics Super-Proxy to make data from Google Analytics publicly available at our website. 
Currently I have a custom query that I'm creating using Google Query Explorer. This contains the top search keywords for a particular User Type, which contains a Japanese word as well. The Japanese term is getting displayed in the Query Explorer website. But when I use the same custom query and run it on GA super proxy site, I get no data in the JSON Response. Any ideas why ?

Regards,
Alok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a unicode issue. I'd recommend reporting it as a bug on the Github repo:
https://github.com/googleanalytics/google-analytics-super-proxy/issues/new

Comment: Thanks, I've submitted it as a bug.